# Вызов JavaScript скрипта

Tags: php, javascript, html

Как я могу вызвать функцию, когда она стоит на onClick event: `<a class="classes" href="javascript:;" onclick="$.Notification.autoHideNotify('error', 'top right', 'Header','Main')">Button</a>`
без eventa на нажатие, то есть допустим, при загрузке страницы

Comment: так есть же событие onLoad https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror

Comment: @dpi Можно примером в коде пожалуйста? Возможно вообще без подключения external файлов?

Comment: `$(function(){ $("#id_вашей_кнопки").click(); }`